Are container engine usage questions off-topic?
This is the question that led me to posting this: Volume on rootless Podman to CIFS mount: Ooperation not supported. The question was generally well-written, with pretty good formatting and plenty of information. Yet it was downvoted into oblivion and closed without so much as a comment. This reason of closure is highly questionable IMO.
Is it really off-topic? I'd imagine the justification for closure is that the voters assumed this is more of a deployment problem, hence is better suited for Server Fault. (Of course, without a comment from said voters, I cannot know for sure.) But that logic is flawed on multiple levels:

First, container technology has far wider scope than "just deployment". It can be used to set up compilation, runtime, or testing environments, which many developers frequently take advantage of during development. This would qualify it as a software tool commonly used by programmers.
Second, depending on the different granularity of specialisation at different workplaces, deployment (or perhaps, making sure the software is deployable) may very well be the developer's responsibility. I doubt anyone would consider questions associated with testing to be off-topic.


Anyway, here are my personal opinions on this matter. I believe the question is very much on-topic and should be reopened. And as an extension, I believe container engine usage questions (in lieu of extenuating circumstances) are generally on-topic.

Some questions about containers are on topic (which is why the tags exist). But it still matters what you are asking about the container. The fact that a container could be used for those purposes isn't what matters. What matters is the specific thing that you are doing with the container, that is integral to the question. This question is purely about creating the container, which is equally well done for non-programming reasons. It is no more "about programming" than "how do I start Notepad?" just because one can edit source code in Notepad.

"Is it really off-topic" - 10 years ago, probably no. Today, probably yes. The "and is a programming problem" bit which is often conveniently ignored in the documentation is more strictly curated nowadays. I say probably because it's dev/ops. There are no guarantees how such questions are going to be judged. I would ask container questions on a more dedicated site if I were you.
